# SQL nested if else if Syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
declare @timeid int

if(datename(Dw,getdate())='Monday')
begin
set @timeid=3
end
Else if(datename(Dw,getdate())='Sunday' or datename(Dw,getdate())='Saturday')
begin
  set @timeId=2
end

ELSE   -- for Tuesday to Friday

begin
 if(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),108)<='08:30:00')
  begin
   set @timeId=1
  end
 else
  begin
   set @timeId=0
  end
end

select @timeid
```

Error is being thrown:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Else'.
>
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '@timeid'.*

Please help.

Comment: What is the output of GETDATE() for you?

Comment: @Nalaka526, I don't see how the result of `GETDATE()` could matter, as this is a compile-time error.

Comment: todays date ..
2013-01-07 08:43:18.843

Comment: This actually runs for me, in SQL Server Express 2008 R2 (the output is 2).  What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Of course, Code works fine on my SQL Server, so i guessed something wrong with the parameter... :)

Comment: be careful with "@timeid" and "@timeId"

Comment: Retagged to include tag for Sql Server 2005 to reflect the appropriate version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'm pretty sure your syntax error is the `varchar(11)` should be `varchar`.

Notwithstanding, this is not good use of SQL; first, you use `getdate()` 3 times - each time will be different (by milliseconds) this could mean ticking over from Friday to Saturday between the first and last call, or from before 08:30 to after 08:30.

Try this:

```
declare @timeid int
declare @nowtime datetime

select @nowtime=getdate()

select @timeid = CASE datename(Dw,@nowtime)
                   WHEN 'Monday' THEN 3
                   WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 2
                   WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 2
                   ELSE
                     CASE 
                       WHEN convert(varchar,getdate(),108)<='08:30:00' THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END
                 END
```

Comment: If the version of SQL Server is 2008 or greater, you can combine your declaration and initialization into a single line:
`declare @nowtime datetime = getdate()`

Comment: Using `varchar(11)` shouldn't throw the error - at the most it will simply truncate the result

Comment: You should **always** define an explicit length for a `varchar` - otherwise you might suddenly end up with a 1-character long string.....

Answer (score 2):

@DaleM beat me to it, but yeah, here's another rewrite for clarity:

```
DECLARE @DOW_SUNDAY int
DECLARE @DOW_MONDAY int
DECLARE @DOW_SATURDAY int

SET @DOW_SUNDAY = 1
SET @DOW_MONDAY = 2
SET @DOW_SATURDAY = 7

DECLARE @now datetime
DECLARE @day_of_week int

SET @now = GETDATE()
SET @day_of_week = DATEPART(DW, @now)

SELECT CASE WHEN @day_of_week = @DOW_MONDAY
            THEN 3
            WHEN @day_of_week IN (@DOW_SATURDAY, @DOW_SUNDAY)
            THEN 2
            WHEN CONVERT(varchar, @now, 108) <= '08:30:00'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
```

Comment: A good example of caching a single value from `GetDate()` and using it thereafter.